# Using events in Drilldown (mdxExpression)

Tags: mdx, iccube

When I try to use events in a mdxExpression drilldown strategy I get an `MDX evaluation internal error: The measure [Measures].[@{sort_by!revenue}] does not exist`:

```
CASE $member.hierarchy.name
    WHEN [TOP_LIST_DIMENSION].[TOP_LIST_ID].name THEN
        TopCount([PRODUCT_DIMENSION].[PRODUCTS].members, 10, [Measures].[@{sort_by!revenue}])
    ELSE ic3drilldownStop()
END
```

If I replace `[Measures].[@{sort_by!revenue}]` with `[Measures].[revenue]` it works as expected, but then I can't change the measure to sort by.

Comment: my educated guess is that events are not supported in the drilldown strategy

Comment: too bad... any plans to implement this in the future? This would be very nice to have.